# How to get apache to run python toolbox?

Tags: python, apache, geopy

So I'm trying to use the geopy toolbox for a school project, but despite working when I run the program on my school's server (where my public_html file is located), I can't get Apache to recognize the toolbox.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print 'content-type: text/html\n'

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
```

I have the geopy folder in the same directory as the python file, so how do I get Apache to recognize geopy?

(I realize a lot of my knowledge is half-baked so please bear with me).

Comment: Lots of stuff needs to be checked. Is python installed and configured correctly with Apache, etc. Check the logs and post it.

Comment: Not sure how to get those... ._.